# Break loop when child process finishes

Tags: python, process, parent-child, pid

I am trying to make a simple program that will start a child process which writes a string to a pipe while the parent process counts until it gets the string from the pipe. My problem however is that when the program runs it'll either not count or will not stop counting. I want to know how I can check if the child process is still running and depending on that break out of the counting loop.

```
import os, time

pipein, pipeout = os.pipe()

def child(input, pipeout):  
    time.sleep(2)
    msg = ('child got this %s' % input).encode()
    os.write(pipeout, msg)

input = input()

pid = os.fork() 
if pid: 
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
        try:
            os.kill(pid, 0)
        except OSError:
            break
    line = os.read(pipein, 32)
    print(line)
else:
    child(input, pipeout)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, and then you can call `poll()`

use popen.poll()

[Explained here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)

```
if Popen.poll() is not None:
    //child process has terminated
```

[edit]:

"The only way to control the input and output streams and also retrieve the return codes is to use the subprocess module; these are only available on Unix."

[Source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.tmpfile)

Comment: `poll` will return None if the process has not yet terminated, and it's exit status if it has. Checking for `< 0` makes no sense.

Comment: Well I'm not using subprocess so it doesn't really help me

Comment: @mata the code for terminated processes is a negative number, you can check for a specific code if you want

Comment: @SebastianRindom well if you decided to use it, then you could achieve this functionality

Comment: @SebastianRindom - Yes, but you'll miss any case where the process has terminated on it's own, so you should rather check for `is not None`

Comment: @mata feel free to edit my answer, your idea is indeed better